# how much memory does Adreno 320 GPU provide?

Tags: graphics, graphics-programming, gpu

I wanted to know how much memory does  Adreno 320 GPU provide ? I am using Nexus 4.

I Googled about it and not able to find any details about it. Can anyone provide the details?

Comment: The GPU does not provide memory. Memory available to GPU is determined by specific device configuration.

Comment: can you explain what device configuration you are talking about ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specifications of a piece of hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose mobiles do not have dedicated Graphics cards (they have integrated GPUs) , so they utilize the RAM available on the device. To measure, you can try to allocate memory for textures until you run out of memory in order find an approximate limit on the VRAM available.